# Python regex - check String for nested loops

Tags: python, regex, string

Input : a String containing a piece of code.

Goal : find if the string input contains :-

- nested loop

e.g.

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for x in fruits:
  print(x)
  for y in x:
     print(y)
```

while...for

I am unable to get the regex for nested loops specially.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Please refer to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on how to ask a good question.

Please include what you have tried so far in your question. SO is not a "code-factory" to write your code. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think this project is a good deal more ambitious than you may realize.

Comment: Thanks @BoarGules  is there some simpler way to just check for nested loops.

Because I am currently checking for loops with just simple text search of 'for' and 'while'.
But not sure how to do the same for nested loop.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't powerful enough to parse Python programs, because Python programs can contain arbitrarily nested parentheses, which are infamously unmatchable using regex. Instead, try using `ast.parse` to get the program's syntax tree. You can iterate over the tree and determine whether it contains two consecutive `For` nodes.

Comment: thanks a lot @Kevin. i will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Kevin s suggestion with "[ast.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)"

I could use

```
def hasRecursion(tree):
    for node in [n for n in ast.walk(tree)]:
            nodecls = node.__class__
            nodename = nodecls.__name__
            if isinstance(node, (ast.For, ast.While)):
                for nodeChild in node.body:     
                    #node.body Or ast.iter_child_nodes(node)
                    if isinstance(nodeChild, (ast.For, ast.While)):
                        return True
return False




expr="""
for i in 3:
   print("first loop")
   for j in i:
        print("nested loop")

print('normal')
"""

tree = ast.parse(expr, mode="exec")

print(hasRecursion(tree))
```

[ast.parse code examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/4282/ast.parse)

Thanks @Kevin